# Store opened tabs of sessions into file

Tags: ranger

Is it possible to store the current ranger session into a file so to restore it at a later point in time?

EDIT: I ask this question because I use many different ranger sessions and tabs inside a tmux session. When I'm storing the tmux session, I'd also like to preserve the ranger tabs.

Answer (score 3):

see `save_tabs_on_exit [bool]`

> Save all tabs, except the active, on exit? The last saved tabs are restored once
>   when starting the next session. Multiple sessions are stored in a stack and the
>   oldest saved tabs are restored first.

Set in your `.config/ranger/rc.conf`:

```
set save_tabs_on_exit true
```

You'll probably need to use [ranger from master](https://github.com/ranger/ranger).

Comment: It's worth noting here that You need to use `F10` for `ranger` to remember tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the new version is not yet available in the official channels.

Comment: @tigerjack89 yes, they don't release very often. The only thing you need to do though is `git clone` the repo and `ln -s` ranger somewhere in your path (after uninstalling the old version).

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz you can remap `q` to `exit` as it stays for `F10` in: `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf`